# How to create DICOM MWL query using dcm4che3 in Java?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am building a DICOM client using the dcm4che3 library and it's a bit confusing to me how I'm supposed to create the dicom query. I'm calling the CFIND method on the `Association` class.

I've figured out how to create a basic query (eg search by PatientID) as follows:

```
Attributes query = new Attributes();
query.setString(Tag.PatientID, VR.LO, "12345");
```

So far so good.

But when I want to query using something like `ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate`, I have to create a Sequence with a sub query something like this:

```
Attributes query = new Attributes();
Sequence sequence = query.newSequence(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepSequence, 1);
Attributes subQuery = new Attributes();
subQuery.setDate(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate, VR.DA, date);
sequence.add(subQuery);
```

I don't know the DICOM format in detail. So I figured this out quite by trial and error and using another DICOM client emulator and intercepting it's queries to try and figure out how it works.

So from this I have 3 questions:

1. How can I query for `ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate` **between** two dates (i.e. using a From and To date).
2. When creating the query, is it possible to have the dcm4che3 library figure out how to make the Sequences, so I can just specify the Tag, VR and value I want in the query?
3. When I query using the Sequence elements (eg `ScheduledProcedureStepSequence` -> `Modality`) it doesn't seem to work. Is there any trick to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I query for `ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate` **between** two dates (i.e. using a From and To date).

The [`Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date`](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ee2/pages/2555955/Modality+Worklist+SCP) (0040,0002) element is part of `Scheduled Procedure Step Sequence` (0040,0100). This supports [Combined Range Matching](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ee2/pages/2555912/Combined+Range+Matching).

> Matching keys for Date and Time are combined. For example, a Study Date of "20060705-20060707" and a Study Time of "1000-1800" will match the time period of July 5, 10am until July 7, 6pm, rather than the three time periods of 10am until 6pm on each of July 5, July 6 and July 7.

So, you can specify two dates separated by dash (`-`) to search *between* two dates. Example is given in quote above.

> 2. When creating the query, is it possible to have the dcm4che3 library figure out how to make the Sequences, so I can just specify the Tag, VR and value I want in the query?

DICOM element hierarchy is very simple; caller can easily create sequences as needed. In majority of the cases, MWL query contain only one sequence that you mentioned.

What you are asking needs a wrapper over basic Data Set class. Most widely used tool kits does not support wrapper over DICOM Data Set to simplify sequence handling; I know few does. I am not expert in the toolkit; but AFAIK, such wrapper does not exist for dcm4che. You have to create and manage sequence elements yourself.

> 3. When I query using the Sequence elements (eg `ScheduledProcedureStepSequence` -> `Modality`) it doesn't seem to work. Is there any trick to make this work?

This is not clear; "*it doesn't seem to work*" does not explain it. Sequence element contains an `Item`. The `Item` contains further elements. Each `Item` can be treated as Data Set again.

Following is how your query should something look like:

[image: MQL Query]

The [article](http://dicomiseasy.blogspot.com/2012/04/dicom-modality-worklist.html) from Roni may be helpful to you. The source code there does not use your toolkit; hope you will get an idea.